# Countable Connected Hausdorff groups

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, connectedness, topological-groups

Does there exist a countable connected Hausdorff (nontrivial) topological group?

I'm aware that countable connected Hausdorff spaces exist (for example the Bing space, the Golomb space, or $\mathbb{Q}P^\infty$), but can any such spaces be made into a topological group?

I also wonder, if such groups do exist, whether any of the groups $\mathbb{Z}^n$, free groups on at most countably many generators, or $\mathbb{Q}$ be given a compatible connected Hausdorff topology?

Comment: Do you know that Hausdorff plus 1st countable implies metrizable for topological groups?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I'm not sure that every countable space is first-countable. E.g., take the union of $\mathbf{N}$ and one more point inside its Stone-Cech compactification. As regards countable topological groups, I'm not sure that the Bohr topology on $\mathbf{Z}$ is first-countable.

Comment: @YCor: You are right...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[No.](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Has%20a%20group%20topology%2B%24T_2%24%2BCountable%2Bconnected%2BHas%20distinct%20points)

Breaking that down: every connected $T_3$ space besides the singleton is uncountable. All Hausdroff topological groups are $T_3$.